# Get path from a StorageVolume

Tags: java, android

How do I get the path for the storeVolume with the code shown below? I am trying to read a file from an OTG usb device, Android 9 (pixel3a, specifically)

```
StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager)context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        List<StorageVolume> storageVolumeList=storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
        String output = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < storageVolumeList.size(); i++) {
            if (storageVolumeList.get(i).isRemovable()){
                output += storageVolumeList.get(i).getUuid();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Intent intent = storageVolumeList.get(i).createAccessIntent(); startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCESS_TO_VOLUME); ( i> 0 ).

Comment: In onActivityResult() Uri uri = data.getData();. Your content scheme path is uri.toString();

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, createAccessIntent is for standard directories? I need to get access to the root of the USB and check for a specific folder, if that folder is there, import the contents.

Comment: You can answer your question yourself if you tried that code. Dont understand you asked. Or otherwise i do not understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`storageVolumeList.get(i).getDirectory()`

to get the path of internal storage.